# NET10 iPhone 4 shows no cellular data service despite plan having cellular data

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

I have a NET10 iPhone 4 and it keeps saying I have no cellular data service and cannot connect to internet. How can I get internet back? NET10 said I show I have internet. I have reset my phone and pretty much tried everything. I am paying for unlimited and have nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: have you gotten any support from Net10 beyond them saying you show you have internet?

Comment: Is this a new problem or did it newer worked ?

Comment: Yes they walked me through a few things and were themselves puzzled. Yes it always worked before.